# CMake how to install test files with unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I am using CMake to build my system and my unit tests.

I am also doing an out-of-source build.

I've found with the ADD_TEST() command, that you don't need to install the test executable (it will just be run when you run make install, which is great).

However, my unit tests depend on some input files, which need to be copied to where the executable is built.

As far as I am aware, I can't use INSTALL() to copy the files there, because I haven't specified where *there* is - it depends on where the build command is called.

Is there some way I can tell CMake to copy my test files to the same location that it builds the executable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but currently I am doing this:

```
file(COPY my_directory DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Which seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Works, but the copy occurs at configuration time.

Answer (score 9):

You may use **configure_file** with parameter **COPYONLY**. And perform copying to your build dir:  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}

Answer (score 8):

The question is quite old, but in my opinion there is a better solution to the problem than copying the files you need to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`. The `add_test` command has a `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option that allows to chose the directory where the tests are run. So I would suggest the following solution:

```
add_executable(testA testA.cpp)
add_test(NAME ThisIsTestA COMMAND testA WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DIRECTORY_WITH_TEST_DATA})
```

This avoids needless copying of your input files.

Comment: While preventing copying all the test data, you take the risk that the test alters your actual test data.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do this on the configuration step this way:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${fileFrom} ${fileTo})
```

If your input files depend on something produced by build, you can create a target for it and add it to the `all` target:

```
add_custom_target(copy_my_files ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${fileFrom} ${fileTo}
    DEPENDS ${fileFrom}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

To copy a whole directory at build time (and only if the build succeeds) you can do this after you added your target (e. g. unit test executable):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testDataDir $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/testDataDir)
```