# Installing unit tests for later execution with ctest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cmake, installation, ctest

I'm building a program intended for execution on another machine, with the target folders being mounted somehow on that other machine (e.g. with NFS or SMB). Since it depends on hardware that's not available on the build machine, `make test` will "fail" for lack of that hardware; or perhaps - it's a cross-platform build and the tests won't even run.

Now, I *do* want to run the unit tests - all of them, using `ctest`, or `make test`, on the target machine. But I can only do that if CMake allows me to `--install-tests` as opposed to `--install`.

Is there some mechanism for install tests for later execution in CMake?

Note: If it somehow only exists in recent versions, that's fine as an answer.

Related: [CMake how to install test files with unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313258/cmake-how-to-install-test-files-with-unit-tests)

Answer (score 1):

> on the target machine.

Write a script that will run the program on the target machine/environment - it will connect to it via ssh or whatever. Use [CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR.html#variable:CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR) and specify that script. `ctest` will execute `${CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR} program args..` and your script can execute the program in target environment. Typically I've seen it's used with `qemu`.

You can also interest yourself in [ctest fixtures](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_REQUIRED.html#prop_test:FIXTURES_REQUIRED).

Comment: 1. But in order to run the test program on the target machine, files need to be transferred (such as libraries etc) 2. So, in the non-cross-compiling case, should I turn on CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING anyway?

Comment: 1. ?? Well, it's a script or a program, so do that in it. So transfer them. 2. Yes, so cmake will not for example add `-rdynamic` to your gcc compiler options . Or `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME generic)`

Comment: 1. But I want CMake to automate this for me... 2. Ok. I always get confused by `-rdynamic` and never keep in mind exactly what it does.